# In keycloak, the same password can have different secrets?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, keycloak, secret-key

I was wondering if the same password on keycloak can have different secrets.
I am asking this because I had a pod with postgres and one with keycloak and the admin password was not working when accessing the keycloak admin page on the browser.
The reason for this was because on the sql dump file I used to restore the DB, there was already an admin user with a secret.
When I removed all the entries for the user admin on the DB dump it worked.
I assume the password for that user was admin and as such was wondering if my keycloak instance would add a different salt and as such the secret created on my machine be different than the secret stored in the DB dump, even for the same password.

Comment: If by "secret" you mean the hash in the database, then yes it is expected to be different every time due to its random generation. However, that doesn't explain why you could not login with the same password as on the original instance.

Comment: The admin user was already in the dump that was exported from azure and which I imported to my pod. This admin user that was on the DB was not created by me.
I think keycloak when I passed KEYCLOAK_USER = admin and KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD = admin on the helm chart creates a secret with a certain salt.
The secret that was on the DB could have a different salt and as such the secrets were different.
I think it compares the generated secret with the secret which is on the DB.
The secret that was on the DB was already there, generated by other instance of keycloak.
As such I was not able to login.

Comment: `KEYCLOAK_USER`/`KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD` creates a new admin user already if one doesn't exist already. This has nothing to do with the salting or whether the secret is different. So you'll have to login with the same credentials that were used in azure.